# excel2latex table too many }s, wrong endgroups, and too many endgroups

Tags: tables, excel

I am having issues inputting a table generated by `excel2latex` into my primary document.

I have called up packages `bookends`. And here is the code copied directly from `excel2latex` (in excel 2010 on a PC):

```
\begin{table}[htbp]  
  \centering  
  \caption{Add caption}  
    \begin{tabular}{rrrr}  
    \toprule  
    Group & Mean1 & Mean2 & Difference \\  
    \midrule  
    Men   & 2.6   & 3.6   & 1.0 \\  
    Women & 6.7   & 8.9   & 2.2 \\  
    \bottomrule  
    \end{tabular}%  
  \label{tab:junk}%  
\end{table}%
```

With this code consistently I get the following 3 errors:

```
Too many }'s \end{table}  
\begin{document} ended by \end{table}. \end{table}  
Extra \endgroup \end{table}
```

However, I can't seem to find any of these errors in the actual code.
I can't seem to get past these errors when the code is directly in the document or when input from a different file (as in `\input{table_junk}`).
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Correction, I'm using the package booktabs.

Comment: You can edit your question to add that

Comment: My suggestion would be to narrow down the problem via a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: Without a full MWE we can't really help here.